# How to set focus on a custom filter dialog in ag-grid react?

Tags: reactjs, accessibility, ag-grid

We're developing a grid that will be used with screen readers. So far ag-grid is pretty accessible, but one issue is setting the focus on a custom filter when it's opened. (Note, the built in filters do set the focus correctly.)

Previous versions of the grid had a function "afterGuiAttached()" that could be used to set the focus after render. But we're using ag-grid-community 25.1.0 and ag-grid-react 25.1.0 and that function no longer exists.

Here is a plunker example and I've pasted a sample custom filter below.
[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview&preview)

```html
import React, {
  forwardRef,
  useEffect,
  useImperativeHandle,
  useState,
  useRef,
} from 'react';

export default forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const [filterText, setFilterText] = useState(null);

  // expose AG Grid Filter Lifecycle callbacks
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => {
    return {
      doesFilterPass(params) {
        // make sure each word passes separately, ie search for firstname, lastname
        let passed = true;
        filterText
          .toLowerCase()
          .split(' ')
          .forEach((filterWord) => {
            const value = props.valueGetter(params);

            if (value.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(filterWord) < 0) {
              passed = false;
            }
          });

        return passed;
      },

      isFilterActive() {
        return filterText != null && filterText !== '';
      },

      getModel() {
        return { value: filterText };
      },

      setModel(model) {
        setFilterText(model.value);
      },
    };
  });

  const onChange = (event) => {
    setFilterText(event.target.value);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    props.filterChangedCallback();
  }, [filterText]);

  return (
    <div style={{ padding: 4, width: 200 }}>
      <div style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Custom Athlete Filter</div>
      <div>
        <input
          style={{ margin: '4 0 4 0' }}
          type="text"
          value={filterText}
          onChange={onChange}
          placeholder="Full name search..."
        />
      </div>
      <div style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
        This filter does partial word search on multiple words, eg "mich phel"
        still brings back Michael Phelps.
      </div>
      <div style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
        Just to emphasise that anything can go in here, here is an image!!
      </div>
      <div>
        <img
          src="https://www.ag-grid.com/images/ag-Grid2-200.png"
          style={{
            width: 150,
            textAlign: 'center',
            padding: 10,
            margin: 10,
            border: '1px solid lightgrey',
          }}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess I'm late to the question, but I was facing the same issue, and I found a workaround. I am using ag-grid **community v26.2.0**. And the way I solved it is below.

Basically, you give your input an ID and on the `onFilterOpened` event, you do a direct focus on the DOM element itself. Of course you could add a small delay using `setTimeout()` if you have some animation set up while the popup is entering in the DOM.

```
<AgGridReact
   {...otherGridOptions}
   onFilterOpened={() => document.querySelector("#idOfYourInput")?.focus()}>
   //columns or other children
</AgGridReact>
```

Comment: I added this code to the function onGridReady and everything works for me:                    
  const onGridReady = (params) => {            
      document.querySelector("#idOfYourInput")?.focus() ...